# Firebase redirect user to a page after clicking verification link

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, web-applications

I'm using firebase in my web app with Ionic and I would like to redirect the user to a specific page (the login page, in my case) after he clicks on the link in the verification email.
At the moment, when the user clicks on the verification link, he is redirected on another browser page that says that he has confirmed the email.

[image]

I would like to redirect him directly to a page of my web app, without passing through that confirmation.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Look in the firebase.console on the left for "Authentication".
Then find "Templates" and look for "Email address verification". I think it's default opened. On the template you will see a small pencil, click on it. After that you can change your template however you want. At the bottom you will find the link "customize action URL". Open this link, paste your URL in the modal window and save. That's it.

[image: First Steps]

[image: Last Steps]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The problem is that I'm currently developing the app locally, so I can't use a specific URL to redirect to my page, because all the pages are at localhost:8100. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I think in the beginning you shouldn't focus on details like redirecting the user after email verficiation, that's just insert a URL and finish.
But if you really want to, you can find any server and domainname for free, upload your project and insert a URL of the domain or server you're using.

Comment: @R.Rasco Would I have to manually verify the user's email in this case. It seems so. I think people are looking for a solution where firebase verifies the email automatically and then redirects to a page of their application

Comment: @Swapnil No, you don't have to. When the user clicks on the verification link, he approves him self and can use the application without any interaction of yours.

Comment: Don't work for me. Just getting the page that required verification (it showed when the email is not verify)

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't get any of the solutions here to work. So after looking up the docs I found that you add a continue URL after the email verification to which the firebase will redirect to after confirming.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions

After email is verified you might also have to force refresh the firebase token if you use `email_verified` in your firebase rules.

You can do what I did.

1. Pass `ActionCodeSettings` to sendEmailVerification.

> ```
>   auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
>   .then((res) => {
>     res.user.sendEmailVerification({
>       url: "https://example.com/path?confirm_email=true",
>     });
>     return createUser({ email, uid: res.user.uid, name });
>   })
> ```

This will make firebase redirect to `https://example.com/path?confirm_email=true` after email verification. The `confirm_email` is so that I know when to force refresh the firebase token.

**(Optional)**

2. Once redirected to the page you want you can check for the confirm_email param and force refresh the token accordingly.

> ```
> const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
> const isConfirmingEmail = urlParams.get('confirm_email');
>
>
> auth.currentUser.getIdToken(!!isConfirmingEmail).then(() => {
>   // Refreshed Token
> })
> ```

Comment: Works! This is exactly the solution I had been waiting for. Thanks!

Comment: While sending ActionCodeSettings is the solution by providing a 'continue' URL. Relying on query params (confirm_email here) to check the 'confirm email' status is a red flag since anyone can send that param in the URL.
Instead use 'user.emailVerified' on the client side to check if the email has been verified.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have Firebase do a Authenticate then redirect unfortunately. The currently accepted answer on this is half-way there. By going into "Firebase -> Authentication -> Templates -> Email Address Verification -> Edit (aka. Pencil button)". You can then click on "Customize action URL" and insert any URL you want here.

**Please note** this URL you enter will not redirect you to the page after performing an email verification. All it will do is instead of generating the link `<firebase email verification link>?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=<code>` it will instead direct you to `<link you put in>?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=<code>`. Meaning that when a user lands on this page you will have to then handle the email verification yourself. Which means parsing out the query params, and sending this information along to Firebase in the back-end to verify the email in question. See the following for  a potential on how to verify the email address: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-confirm-email-verification

More information about this can be found here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code that helped me. I am only providing you necessary code that you need You have to fill rest of the code by yourself.

Firebase v9 example

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendEmailVerification
} from "@firebase/auth";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom"

export default function SignUp() {
  const history = useHistory()
  async function submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // Prevent default.

    // Sign your user using createUserWithEmailAndPassword

    // Provide user's email and password
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    // Send verification email.
    await sendEmailVerification(userCredentials.user);

    let interval = setInterval(async() => {
      if (userCredentials.user.emailVerified) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        history.push("/desired-link");
      }
      await userCredentials.user.reload();
    }, 2000);
  }
  return < > { /* your sign up form */ } < />;
}
```

Firebase v8 code:

```js
import React from "react";
import firebase from "firebase"
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom"

export default function SignUp() {
    const history = useHistory()
    async function submit(e) {
        e.preventDefault() // Prevent default.
        
        // Sign your user using createUserWithEmailAndPassword
        
        // Provide user's email and password
        let userCredentials = await firebase.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

        // Send verification email.
        await userCredentials.user.sendEmailVerification()

        let interval = setInterval(async () => {
            if (userCredentials.user.emailVerified) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                history.push("/desired-link");
            }
           await  userCredentials.user.reload();
        }, 2000);
    }
    return <>{/* your sign up form */}</>;
}
```

As soon as user clicks the verification link, he will find your webpage redirects to `<domain.name>/desired-link`.

However, a bonus tip for you... **Do not manipulate the action url.** It's because by doing that, `firebase.auth.currentUser.emailVerified` will always return false. Meaning, user email would never be verified. It's because this action URL is responsible for email  verification. So, instead of doing that, follow my example. This works for both localhost and your custom domain.

Comment: Great solution! Though I think the [v9 `reload`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#reload) should be `reload(user)`. And maybe you missed the `await`?